# Is this sentence referring to an individual or a group of people?

Tags: word-choice, particle-こと

> それでもあいつが絶対的[窮地]{きゅうち}に立ったら迷わず[助太刀]{すけだち}に入る事

I know it says something like "If he gets into a really dangerous situation, I'll/We'll be at his side in a second!"

My question is, would a more correct translation of this be "I'll" or "We'll"? Could it be either one, depending on context? And could it have a double meaning, depending on the speaker's intention? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, it means neither. こと like this at the end of the sentence forms a command, "*You* must (be at his side)".

- [こと as an Imperative](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40951/5010)
- [What do I do when I encounter "Written Japanese"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3878/5010)

In an uncommon context, it is also possible that this こと is just a normal nominalizer. "Being at his side once he gets into ..."

Comment: In the OP's example, would you expect こと to be written in kana?

Comment: @snailplane Yes, usually.